# How to pass a callable defined in my django app to a third-party django app via my project settings.py?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to pass a function defined in my views.py, by specifying a specific setting in settings.py, to a third-party django app used by my project like the following:

```
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PAGE_LIST_CALLABLE = myapp.views.get_pagination_pages
```

and I got the error `NameError: name 'lend_borrow' is not defined`

Then I tried

```
import myapp
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PAGE_LIST_CALLABLE = myapp.views.get_pagination_pages
```

and another error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'`

I also attempted with passing the path to the callable:

```
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PAGE_LIST_CALLABLE = 'myapp.views.get_pagination_pages'
```

But the third-party app doesn't seem to like it. I got `Caught TypeError while rendering: 'str' object is not callable`

The third-party app being used here is [django endless pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). It's included in INSTALLED_APPS.

How can I pass the callable defined in my app to the third-party app via settings.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the expectation of the app is the callable and not a string. So, if it works, this should work:

```
from myapp.views import get_pagination_pages
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PAGE_LIST_CALLABLE = get_pagination_pages
```

However, you should know that `settings` is loaded before any of the other files, and if you try to load a views file that imports from models and that in-turn requires settings to be loaded, there can be a circular import and probably the best way to avoid it is by placing the function in a file that doesn't `import models`, say `utils.py` or something like that.

If the function is simple enough, I'd put it in `settings` itself, or a file parallel to that.

Comment: Thanks Lakshman.Everything makes sense after you explained.I think I am going to put the function in `settings.py` for now. For the long-run, I'll fork the third-party app and modify it to accept a string of the path to the callable.